# Register Hotkey

Tags: c#, .net, windows, vb.net

I have this function:
RegisterGlobalHotKey(Keys.F6, MOD_SHIFT | MOD_CONTROL);
which call an API to register a global shortcut key in the system.
void RegisterGlobalHotKey(Keys hotkey, int modifiers)

I created a small options form to set this keys to be variables not fixed values like this:
RegisterGlobalHotKey(VARIABLE1, VARIABLE2 | VARIABLE3);

See the attached option form to understand more

The main problem is how to convert the combobox string values to Keys enum value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you can require users to type in the name of the Enum values exactly, you can pass the text to `Enum.Parse` and that will return the enum value with the specified name.

Answer (score 0):

How about a map of your strings to Keys, and your other strings to modifiers?

Map
Map

That would avoid a bunch of if-else string comparisons in your code.

EDIT: Actually, I think I've also used Andy's suggestion in the past as well.